# React-Native Animated.interpolate doesn't work with Styled-Components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, styled-components, react-animated

Does anybody know why the Animated.interpolate function doesn't work with Styled-Components.. or what I am doing wrong?

**Environment**

- Node: 12.13.0
- npm: 6.12.0
- react-native: 0.62
- styled-components: ^5.1.1 => 5.1.1
- @types/styled-components: ^5.1.0 => 5.1.0

**Steps to Reproduce**

1. Create a new TypeScript react-native project with **npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript**
2. Install **styled-components** and **@types/styled-components**
3. Replace the code of the App.tsx with

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Animated,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import styled, {ThemeProvider} from 'styled-components/native';


const App = () => {

// Animation
  const boxAnimation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  const moveIn = () => {
    Animated.timing(boxAnimation, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 2000,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };
  const moveOut = () => {
    Animated.timing(boxAnimation, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 2000,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };
  const fadeAnim = boxAnimation.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, 1],
  });
  const moveAnim = boxAnimation.interpolate({
    inputRange: [0, 1],
    outputRange: [0, -50],
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={{}}>
      <AnimatedBox opacity={fadeAnim} pos={moveAnim}/>
      <Animated.View style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: moveAnim,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        opacity: fadeAnim,
        backgroundColor: 'green',
      }}/>
      <View style={{marginTop: 100}}>
        <Button title={'MoveIn'} onPress={() => moveIn()}/>
        <Button title={'MoveOut'} onPress={() => moveOut()}/>
      </View>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

const Box = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: ${props => props.pos}px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  opacity: ${props => props.opacity};
  background-color: red;
`;
const AnimatedBox = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Box);

export default App;
```

**Expected Behavior**

The **red Box** (colored View) should fade in and move into the screen if you click the **MoveIn Button** and should fade out and move out if you click the **MoveOut Button**.
(See expected behavior **green box** with normal inline styles)

**Actual Behavior**

The **red Box** will always stay at the position -50 and fades out by clicking the **MoveOut Button** and fade in if you click the **MoveIn Button** (See if you set the pos of the red box to 0)

-> The interpolate function only works with the output range of **0, 1** and **1, 0** which shouldn't be so.. As I said if you are using the normal react-native StyleSheet the interpolate function works as expected..

**GitHub Issue:** https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/3185

Thank you ^^

Comment: <AnimatedBox opacity={fadeAnim} pos={moveAnim}/> <==== what is 'pos'???

Comment: pos is simply the a absolute position left .. so if pos === 20 the box will be 20px away from the left side

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with "styled" but without it you can try to set left with constant number and then swap

```
pos={moveAnim}
```

with

```
style={{ transform: [{ translateX: moveAnim }] }}
```

Comment: yeah.. as I said with inline styles its working perfect.. but I want to avoid inline styled.. because of that I am using styled-components